# Small gap around \color{}

Tags: color, kerning

I'd like to change the color of a few letters in a word. I use the following commands:

```
... \color{g}a\color{d}way ..., or ... a\color{g}way \color{d} ...
```

Here, d is the default color, g is defined as a new color and the letters in the word "away" are altered as shown above. This solution typically works; however, in the above case, a small gap is inserted before the letter w. I've noticed that this gap appears only for the letter w. In my opinion, this is a bug in the program. I use beamer class and compile with pdflatex. I'd be grateful if someone can tell me how to fix this problem. I've tried to compile with latex then go with dvi to pdf, but that produces the same error.

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind to upload an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) such that others can see more easily what you mean?

Comment: no it is not a bug, it is acting as documented. The font will supply inter-letter kerns (spacing) to _consecutive_ runs of letters but if you insert colour on/colour off commands between the letters then you will not see that you will see the same with `\mbox{V}o` compared to `Vo` similarly two consecutive ff will make a single ff ligature but `\textcolor{red}{f}f` will make two separate characters which will have very different spacing in most fonts.

Comment: It would be better to use `\textcolor{g}{a}way` than `\color{g}a\color{d}way` as otherwise you are stacking up a lot of unnecessary colour restores at the end of the current environment (but it will not change the space)

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, a macro that automatically restores the kerns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{cw}{red!80!green}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cw}{m}
 {
  \leavevmode
  \foo_cw:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \foo_cw:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__foo_cw_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (.?)\<(.{1})\>(.?) }
   { \c{__foo_cw_single:nnn}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cB\{\2\cE\}\cB\{\3\cE\} }
   \l__foo_cw_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (.?)\<(.?) }
   { \c{__foo_cw_start:nn}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cB\{\2\cE\} }
   \l__foo_cw_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (.?)\>(.?) }
   { \c{__foo_cw_end:nn}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cB\{\2\cE\} }
   \l__foo_cw_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__foo_cw_tl
 }

\box_new:N \l__foo_cw_unkerned_box
\box_new:N \l__foo_cw_kerned_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_cw_kern:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__foo_cw_unkerned_box { \hbox:n { #1 } \hbox:n { #2 } }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__foo_cw_kerned_box { #1#2 }
  \kern \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l__foo_cw_kerned_box - \box_wd:N \l__foo_cw_unkerned_box } \scan_stop:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_cw_single:nnn
 {
  #1
  \__foo_cw_kern:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \textcolor{cw}{#2}
  \__foo_cw_kern:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  #3
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_cw_start:nn
 {
  #1
  \__foo_cw_kern:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_begin:
  \color{cw}
  #2
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_cw_end:nn
 {
  #1
  \group_end:
  \__foo_cw_kern:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

away        away        away

\cw{<a>way} \cw{a<w>ay} \cw{awa<y>}

\cw{<aw>ay} \cw{a<wa>y} \cw{aw<ay>}

\end{document}
```

A sequence like `x<a>y` (where either `x` or `z` can be missing) is transformed into `\__foo_cw_single:nnn{x}{a}{z}` that later becomes

```
x<kern between x and a>\textcolor{cw}{a}<kern between a and y>y
```

A sequence like `x<a...b>y` (with more than one letter between `<` and `>`) becomes

```
x\__foo_cw_start:nn{x}{a}...\__foo_cw_end:nn{b}{y}
```

that is later transformed to give

```
x<kern between x and a>\begingroup\color{cw}a...b\endgroup<kern between b and y>y
```

The kern between two letters `u` and `v` is computed by subtracting the width of `\hbox{\hbox{u}\hbox{v}}` from the width of `\hbox{uv}`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

If you add `\showoutput` you can see all the kerns that the font adds. Somewhat unusually here `away` gets `\kern-0.27779pt` between each letter, so you can correct as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

away away away away

\textcolor{red}{a}way a\textcolor{red}{w}ay aw\textcolor{red}{a}y awa\textcolor{red}{y}

\textcolor{red}{a}\kern-0.27779pt way
a\kern-0.27779pt \textcolor{red}{w}\kern-0.27779pt ay
aw\kern-0.27779pt\textcolor{red}{a}\kern-0.27779pt y
awa\kern-0.27779pt\textcolor{red}{y}


\end{document}
```